# Python: How to add two lists with no duplicate values for the same key as a value of that key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, combiners

I have this file:

```
domain|nsservers
virus.am.|['ns101.yourhostservice.com.', 'ns102.yourhostservice.com.']
rochemme.ae.|['auhans1.ecompany.ae.', 'auhans2.ecompany.ae.', 'dxbans1.ecompany.ae.', 'dxbans2.ecompany.ae.']
virus.am.|['ns101.yourhostservice.com.', 'ns102.yourhostservice.com.','ns103.yourhostservice.com.']
rochemme.ae.|['auhans2221.ecompany.ae.']
```

I would like to create a new file with this format.

```
domain|list of all unique nsservers
 virus.am.|['ns101.yourhostservice.com.', 'ns102.yourhostservice.com.','ns103.yourhostservice.com.']
 rochemme.ae.|['auhans1.ecompany.ae.', 'auhans2.ecompany.ae.', 'dxbans1.ecompany.ae.', 'dxbans2.ecompany.ae.','auhans2221.ecompany.ae.']
```

Here is the code I used. but it does not give me the result I want:

```
from collections import defaultdict


file = './test'
dns_dic = defaultdict(set)

f = open(file,'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    domain,nslist = line.split('|')
    if domain in dns_dic:
        dns_dic[domain].append(nslist)
    else:
        dns_dic[domain] = (nslist)
print(dns_dic)
```

How can I combine these lists to a unique valie for a key (in this case domain name?) Can anybody help me?

Comment: You question is going to be closed because you did not provide any code

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai Just added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) like -

```
dns_dic = defaultdict(set)
```

This means that `set()` would be used as default value for a key that is not found in the dictionary. But this does not mean that the values in you directly include in the dictionary (using - `dns_dic[domain] = (nslist)` ) would be converted to `set` ) . No such conversion would occur when you directly set a string/list to it.

And another thing is you are using `defaultdict` so that you do not have to check whether the key already exists or not, etc. But still you are doing that check - `if domain in dns_dic:` . You do not need that.

Another issue -

1. `nslist` is a string (not a list) , and hence it does not have any `.append()` method, and hence this should be erroring out for you - `dns_dic[domain].append(nslist)` .

You should make use of `defaultdict`'s ability to create the `set` by default instead of assigning value directly. Only then you would get sets as values. For this you can do something like - `dns_dic[domain].update(nslist)`

And you should use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string to a `list` before adding it to the dictionary/set.

Also, you should use `with` statement to open the file (so that it handles closing the file automatically for you.

Example -

```
from collections import defaultdict
import ast

file = './test'
dns_dic = defaultdict(set)

with open(file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        domain,nslist = line.split('|')
        nslist = ast.literal_eval(nslist)
        dns_dic[domain].update(nslist)

print(dns_dic)
```

After this you can open a file and write the elements of the dictionary to the file. Example -

```
with open('filetowrite','w') as of:
    for k,v in dns_dic.items():
        of.write('{}|{}'.format(k,v))
```